# How do I access document object in pre update mongoose middle-ware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

consider, I have a mongoose schema like this

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.schema({
val1:Number,
val2:Number
val_1_isBigger:Boolean})
```

Now I want to compare both the val1 & val2 before every update opearation and accordingly I wanna set Boolean attribute for val_1_isBigger.

**My question is how do I access document object during pre('update') mongoose plugin operation. Look at following example**

```
mySChema.plugin(function(schema, options) {
    schema.pre('update', function(next) {

//Here How Do I compare val1 & val2 before update happens
//and then set value here accordingly

  this.update({}, { $set: { val_1_isBigger: true/false } });

}
}
```

Comment: any updates about this issue ?

Comment: no @Maysara I didn't find anything which could solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is using the _conditions parameter to get the document with the id of the Query. With the document then you can do the necessary operations and then set the new object to update with _update. 
My code looks like this:

```
userSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
    if (this._conditions) {
        _id = this._conditions.id || '';
        User.findOne({ id : _id }).exec().then((user) => {
            if (user.token === undefined) {
                this._update['$set'].token = 'some token';
                next();
            }
        }); 
    }
    next();
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I guess it could solve the problem but not the best way to achieve the solution because it will cause extra find query during every update operation which is not a best practice. Anyway thanks for your efforts to post answer

Comment: You are right. But it is the only way I could think of doing it inside the pre middleware.